# CSS size/performance?

Tags: html, css, performance

Looking at this css file (*especially the last **5** lines*):

```
#page section .s_1 { overflow:hidden; width:435px; float:left;}
#page section .s_1 h1 { font-size:36pt; color:#001744; line-height:1.1; margin-bottom:64px;height:107px;}
#page section .s_1 menu { list-style:none;padding:0; margin:0;} 
#page section .s_1 menu li { float:left; padding:0; margin:0;} 
#page section .s_1 menu li a {background-image:url(../images/icon_buttons.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; width:79px; height:79px; display:block;}
#page section .s_1 menu li + li {margin-left:10px;}
#page section .s_1 menu li.b_1 a { background-position:0 0;}
#page section .s_1 menu li.b_2 a { background-position:-89px 0;}
#page section .s_1 menu li.b_3 a { background-position:-178px 0;}
#page section .s_1 menu li.b_4 a { background-position:-267px 0;}
#page section .s_1 menu li.b_5 a { background-position:-357px 0;}
...
```

Is this big CSS file is the correct way of writing CSS's ?

I see this kind of hierarchy in many sites.

The CSS file should be small, why does it need all these redundant selectors?

It's possible to use only Id's which will be parsed *much* faster, and of course - the CSS will smaller.

I could shrink this css file by converting this to id's where I can. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Writing_Efficient_CSS)

Comment: @PranavKapoor yeah I already saw it. it says "_The single biggest cause of slowdown is too many rules in the tag category_". But gain , I see it in a lot of sites. Just wanted to know if im not missing something

Comment: @downvoter - thanks . ( for down-voting with(out) explaining your reason)

Comment: Upvoting.. just to counter the downvote without comment..

Comment: @RoyiNamir : I'm assuming it is for maintainability. No one wants to write a lot of `ID's`.

Comment: @PranavKapoor I prefere to write id's ( for the last 5 lines) rathere than larger css file ....no ? ( please consider this question as a megasite POV conflict)

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yup, `id's` above make more sense. I meant it in a general way.

Comment: @RoyiNamir : I usually assume google does take performance very seriously, and prettifying the inline style source, they do seem to use mostly single `class` or `id` selectors

Comment: @PranavKapoor do you mean  - css of google ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir : Yes, [google.com](https://www.google.com/)

Comment: @PranavKapoor yeah I also prettified it   and they use inline style with many Id's ! (maybe 3 percent of cascading elements....)

Comment: FYI Check out this link: "You should style almost everything with classes... Classes are our friends. Seeing a lot of IDs is actually very bad." http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2011/04/28/our-best-practices-are-killing-us/

Comment: @Nick you didnt understand the article. it doesnt say not to use Id's but saying dont use neted ide's like `#sidebar #accounts #accountDetails h3{}`. From my experience. we should User classes when we need to group elements to apply style while id should be specific. example : you have 5 span's and they all have class which is called : .notSelected.   if you press on a span you put class of .selected. if you press another span , you remove .selected and put it on another one.

Comment: What you say is true and I use that technique myself. The deeper point that Nicole was making, however, concerned "specificity" and not just nested ids. (It's clearest in the talk slides.) She is arguing that (1) although one id search is always faster than one class search (as we both know), (2) taking an id approach can cause you a problem across a large scale project. You win the battle but lose the war. As she says in one of the last slides, "Keep specificity as low as possible." You might not agree, but it's not the case that I didn't understand what she was saying :)

Comment: @Nick yeah. sorry thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that adding ID's (or classes) will make parsing of css faster.

The type of code you displayed in your question could very well be a skin for an existing piece of software where the skin developer does not have the option to add id's to all the elements he wants to style. In this case one would have to resort to using the hierarchy to style specific items.

But to summarize:
Using id or classes is indeed faster and the best way to apply styles.

Comment: you are right. this css came from a third party company which designed our site. i believe they used some skin. So youre saying I SHOULD **CHANGE** THIS CSS AND PUT ID's WHEREVER I CAN ?

Comment: Well that all depends on the time you are willing to spend on something that would save you mere milliseconds. Using ID's/classes is faster, and I would encourage that in a new environment. But unless you are dealing with a huge CSS file that takes ages to load, i would keep things as they are. Your faster parse time would only be slightly noticable, possibly making it not worth the effort.

Answer (score 2):

Using `id`'s will be much faster in terms of `CSS` parsing.

From [Mozilla Dev](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Writing_Efficient_CSS),

> Use the most specific category possible
>
> The single biggest cause of slowdown is too many rules in the tag
>   category. By adding classes to our elements, we can further subdivide
>   these rules into Class Categories, which eliminates time spent trying
>   to match rules for a given tag.

Here is a [good research](http://perfectionkills.com/profiling-css-for-fun-and-profit-optimization-notes/) on this subject, which states this as well.

> Most expensive selectors tend to be universal ones ("*"), and those
>   with multiple classes (".foo.bar", "foo .bar.baz qux", etc.). We
>   already knew this, but it’s nice to get confirmation from profilers.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd [use only id's the selection would be faster](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Writing_Efficient_CSS), but you would also have to do more selections than if you would use classes. Provided that the css is clean. Problem with basing style on id's in general is that you forgo all reuse of that style.

The best way to go is to link style to classes. That gives you adequate speed and keeps the css file smaller. Smaller files are much more important for performance in most sites than faster execution on the client. Typical clients will render a complex page in microseconds, once they have all the resources that is.

The css you point out is using a sprite, which could very well be generated with compass or something similar. It's important to see the original code too before making harsh judgements about the quality.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested particularly in the last 5 lines, the `class` vs `id` debate isn't the main thing here.

The fifth line and lines 7-11 (the last five) are referencing the sprite. (I'm sure you know this.) Using six lines to refer to five different images is as efficient as you're going to get.

Furthermore, sprites generally use classes because the image will be deployed in various places.

The CSS efficiency question for these lines is whether the full reference is necessary.

> UPDATE: [This Google document](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rendering) is priceless because it explains how the browser goes about parsing CSS. As a result, it qualifies some of
>   what I wrote below. The browser works right to left for each selector, so
>   **it will never parse `page section`**. The issue is only one of load time.

`#page section .s_1 menu li.b_5 a` could just as well be `.b_5 a` if that's the only context the sprite is used. I'd also put the class on the `<a>` myself, and the you could just refer to the button class as `.b_5`. A better className wouldn't go astray, either IMO; the extra five characters in `button_5` aren't going to kill anyone :)

Overall, you could almost certainly lose `#page section` with no loss of exactitude and gains in performance. The use of `menu` is very likely unnecessary, too.

At the very least, you could undoubtedly strip it back to the following:

```
* {padding:0; margin:0;} /* Assuming this is already standard */
.s_1 { overflow:hidden; width:435px; float:left;}
.s_1 h1 { font-size:36pt; color:#001744; line-height:1.1; margin-bottom:64px;height:107px;}
.s_1 menu { list-style:none;} 
.s_1 li { float:left;} 
.s_1 menu li + li {margin-left:10px;}
.s_1 a {background-image:url(../images/icon_buttons.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; width:79px; height:79px; display:block;}
.b_1 { background-position:0 0;}
.b_2 { background-position:-89px 0;}
.b_3 { background-position:-178px 0;}
.b_4 { background-position:-267px 0;}
.b_5 { background-position:-357px 0;}
```

Personally, I think `.b_1,.b_2,.b_3,.b_4,.b_5` is better that `.s_1 a`. It's also usually unnecessary to have `background-repeat:no-repeat;` if you're using a sprite and specifying the height and width (unless the width is larger than the sprite).

If you're feeling REALLY keen, you can lose the final `;` before the `}` too :)

Comment: `.s_1 a` (the descendants selector) is very bad decision

Comment: @RoyiNamir  Yes. I'm rethinking the `*` for the `padding:0; margin:0` because `*` is seemingly not that efficient, although it's fairly standard practice.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Writing_Efficient_CSS#Avoid_the_descendant_selector.21

Comment: no . leave the *  alone...:-)   Im using a css reset file :-)

Comment: +1 for the removing the last `;` :-)..... it is required only between rules. not in the end.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Great link! I'll be going through my CSS tomorrow :)

Comment: @RoyiNamir The other factor, of course, is that putting in heaps of classes slows down class-based searches (such as with `jQuery`) which I use a lot. So I'm happy to wear a few descendant selectors :)

Comment: yeah. HOwever be sure to remember that same selectors can be better in ie vs chrome, but some other selectors can be better in chrome vs ie. ( better i mean by faster)

Answer (score 0):

If the page is smaller using ID may be senseful. But imagine that there are five lists in your  page and each has five list items under it. Then, you have to define 5*5 ID to use in css. It will be a large text and it will be a bad syntax. Moreover, one item can take more then one class. There fore each class can be used a lot of times (Like inheritance in object oriented). It will also reduce the size of the css text and increase its readability.

Comment: I didnt talk about putting id onn every IL. I meant putting ID on Menu and ofcourse first child selector.(>) I'm just saying i could remove the bloody `#page section .s_1`

Comment: Again you need to define five IDs to use first child selector. Removing "#page section" may be senseful but .s_1 is better then #s_1 to have a readable, small size css.